# Which algorithms are suitable for time series classification for this form of data?

Tags: classification, time-series, lstm, transformer

Newbie here, I have a large list of csv files that contain a series of probability distributions (for 5 classes). I'm trying to train a binary classifier that classifies each file into either a positive or negative class (think medical data). A file would look something like this:

```
5.716146182185134483e-01,1.570351925479201299e-02,7.879747111130347426e-03,2.257236373138224450e-03,4.025448790424259182e-01
9.282036396626092145e-01,1.350252924774404326e-02,1.202944234922503821e-03,1.077829667771727410e-04,5.698310388794716047e-02
7.827619863407961898e-01,1.238710984142047805e-01,4.863074012493366800e-03,1.025238277112187050e-04,8.840131740479445499e-02
9.164564167759865487e-01,5.029982363205267454e-02,1.889329141871147781e-03,3.470568579893339639e-05,3.131972476429063790e-02
8.438599468843770435e-01,1.249894809120763589e-01,4.892015882596660245e-03,6.318069857265228148e-05,2.619537562237720871e-02
7.927862899191280288e-01,1.836963229227321637e-01,8.236097888524881658e-03,7.672725903457503882e-05,1.520456201058032440e-02
6.938920913668409352e-01,1.154946186794907348e-01,4.775610289402269087e-03,6.998382596026862888e-05,1.857676958383056576e-01
5.260109666876285894e-01,5.373236552754552531e-02,2.351633924538396904e-03,5.219686669895120705e-05,4.178528369935886611e-01
3.048328823074770155e-01,6.639936048941325053e-02,2.493391932535035486e-03,3.446025521901748158e-05,6.262399050153556468e-01
4.090438902597091086e-01,8.938231982641510476e-02,3.129738246458822065e-03,4.481533923136918172e-05,4.983992363281855020e-01
3.390709739657606914e-01,7.605934289910418200e-02,2.752420617374790393e-03,4.097357351008719444e-05,5.820762889442502308e-01
6.149776057156663978e-01,7.070150093100460720e-02,2.396856449071802474e-03,3.329015183386138958e-05,3.118907467524231758e-01
5.370645930556066094e-01,1.300161777734864521e-01,3.121570148930582871e-03,2.977214131925493871e-05,3.297678868806570573e-01
4.034325013246508052e-01,1.843589776745651332e-01,4.607250776903500968e-03,3.698432440481392170e-05,4.075642858994759088e-01
4.864387774152492128e-01,2.113910367664585677e-01,4.652455876671098348e-03,2.834732864475179149e-05,2.974893826129763608e-01
2.994464950642671264e-01,3.608846139880280690e-01,7.909903942206513577e-03,2.764288414682062749e-05,3.317313441213514680e-01
3.384097307003371413e-01,3.577836317319948445e-01,9.840109811059946296e-03,3.679938546258189509e-05,2.939297283711455044e-01
.
.
.
.
```

While I understand I can take the argmax for each row and get a much simpler time series, in my particular use case (medical diagnosis) including the probabilities of different classes might be beneficial to the model. My initial plan was to either use transformer encoder -> MLP -> softmax ([from this article](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/)) or a simple LSTM, but I don't know how I can fit this form of data to those algorithms. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: This is very much possible with the architectures you mention, but I wont be writing a tutorial on LSTMs or Transformers as an answer. I recommend you just start looking into LSTMs, code one up, and see how you can fit it. There is plenty of good tutorials out there for LSTMs. Start with that (because they are simpler). If they are not good enough, come back for help on improvements or go into transformers. However, depending on how long your timeseries are, LSTMs should be more then sufficient

Comment: First of all, do NOT start with a transformer. An LSTM is enough of a pain to get working as a noob, you're gonna end up smashing your computer if you start with a transformer. If you don't have experience with an MLP, play around with one, then move to an LSTM architecture IF YOUR DATA IS SEQUENTIAL. I recommend checking out this video: https://youtu.be/7sB052Pz0sQ